# Bypass wait_for_edge with PyQt action

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I can't bypass a wait_for_edge() that is running in a thread in my PyQt interface app working on raspberry pi

So to run the interface i use the following code

```
class initUI:
    global t

    def __init__(self):
        global t
        global MainWindow
        self.gui = ui7.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.gui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.gui.botaocancelar.clicked.connect(self.accaoCancelar)

        t = threading.Thread(target= self.principal)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

I have to create a thread so the view will appear and the program continues

After that the target functions starts working , the code is:

```
    def principal(self):
        while count < int(quantidadeDoArtigo):
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(9, GPIO.FALLING )
```

Whenever the function its called it gets stuck waiting for the pi 9 to get connected and that is correct if the program is running , but i have a button on the interface to close the program (accaoCancelar).

My problem is when i click that button the program gets frozen because the wait_for_edge is blocking my while loop that cannot be broken and that way the app would close .

Any help ?

Comment: `self.accaoCancelar` function  first line  set all parameters for ending(like count = 9**9).

Comment: i already have tried that . It doesn't work because the app is stuck in the line             GPIO.wait_for_edge(9, GPIO.FALLING ) . Only if i do the GPIO falling the while condition will evaluate again . I want to go forward without connection the GPIO

Comment: `while count < int(quantidadeDoArtigo) and need_connection != False:` set `need_connection = False` if want to finished thread.

Comment: @dsgdfg how can that code stop the thread ?

Comment: i edited your question, check for changes. But be careful you need set all variables or conditions to default.